# Send cursor to add to another listview

Tags: android, listview

I am getting the row of an employee clicked in one listview, passing that back to the MainActivity. I am then trying to pass that to another Adapter that will update its ListView and add that row the user clicked on. I am adding the employee(probably not the best as they already have a row inside the database) to the db. Then I am creating a cursor that grabs that row out and trying to changeCursor to the topAdapter(the listView adapter I am trying to update).

I am getting NullPointerException on `topAdapter.changeCursor(clcikedEmployee):`

I don't  think creating a new TopListCursorAdapter would work as I don't want to create a new one, just update and add the new row to the existing list that is inside of it. I know e is not null as when I print it to the console I am getting the data for the clicked user correctly. Just not able to pass it to the TopAdapter to add the row to the exsisting listview.

Is it possible to pass to the TopFragment and update the TopListCursorAdapter from there to have the new row added to the list?

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements BottomListViewAdapter.BottomListClickListener {
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    EmployeeDBHandler dbHandler;
    private TopListCursorAdapter topAdapter;
    private BottomListViewAdapter bottomAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Employee> mEmployee;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        dbHandler = new EmployeeDBHandler(getApplicationContext());
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        getXMLData();

        //GUI for seeing android SQLite Database in Chrome Dev Tools
        Stetho.InitializerBuilder inBuilder = Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(this);
        inBuilder.enableWebKitInspector(Stetho.defaultInspectorModulesProvider(this));
        Stetho.Initializer in = inBuilder.build();
        Stetho.initialize(in);
    }

    public void getXMLData() {
        OkHttpClient client = getUnsafeOkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(getString(R.string.API_FULL_URL))
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                final String responseData = response.body().string();
                final InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseData.getBytes());
                final XMLPullParserHandler parserHandler = new XMLPullParserHandler();
                final ArrayList<Employee> employees = (ArrayList<Employee>) parserHandler.parse(stream);

                for (Employee e : employees) {
                    dbHandler.addEmployee(e);
                }

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        displayTopList();
                        displayBottomList();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    public void displayTopList() {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.topFragment, new TopFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    public void displayBottomList() {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.bottomFragment, new BottomFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }



@Override
public void onBottomListClick(Employee e) {
    dbHandler.addEmployee(e);
    Log.i("EMPLOYEE", e.toString());
    TopFragment topFragment = (TopFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.topFragment);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
    final Cursor clickedEmployee = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + "employees" + " WHERE " +
            "Employee_number" + "=" + e.getEmployee_number(), null);
    // change the adapter's Cursor
    topFragment.update(clickedEmployee);
}
```

}

TopFragment

```
public class TopFragment extends Fragment {
    public Cursor mTopCursor;
    EmployeeDBHandler dbHandler;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_list, container, false);
        String table = "employees";
        int mStartingEmployeeID = 3500075;
        dbHandler = new EmployeeDBHandler(getContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
        mTopCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE " + "Employee_number" + "=" + mStartingEmployeeID, null);
        ListView mTopListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.mTopList);
        TopListCursorAdapter topAdapter = new TopListCursorAdapter(getContext(), mTopCursor);
        mTopListView.setAdapter(topAdapter);

        return view;
    }

public void update(Cursor cursor) {
        MergeCursor mergeCursor = new MergeCursor(new Cursor[]{
                        mTopCursor, cursor });
    }
}
```

Bottom Fragment

```
public class BottomFragment extends Fragment {
    public Cursor mBottomCursor;
    EmployeeDBHandler dbHandler;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom_list, container, false);
        dbHandler = new EmployeeDBHandler(getContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
        String table = "employees";
        int mStartingEmployeeID = 3500075;
        mBottomCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE " +
                "Employee_number" + "!=" + mStartingEmployeeID + " AND " +
                "Manager_employee_number" + "=" + mStartingEmployeeID + " ORDER BY " +
                "Last_name" + " ASC", null);
        ListView mBottomListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        BottomListViewAdapter mBottomAdapter = new BottomListViewAdapter(getContext(), mBottomCursor);
        mBottomListView.setAdapter(mBottomAdapter);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't asigned any value to `topAdapter` in the snipet above (then NPE ?)

Comment: NPE? If I assign it to new TopListCursorAdapter I don't get the null point but nothing happens.

Comment: NPE : NullPointerException.

Comment: You CAN NOT call a method from a null instance, that is a NPE perse. You have to define that adapter to return the view based on the data you are giving it. You know how adapters work ?

Comment: Believe so, you pass the adapter an object(or cursor in the case) then tie the adapter to a listView. The adapter is placing the data where you want it in the listview. But how do I define the adapter so it doesn't create a new one, just adds the row I want to it?

Comment: Your topAdapter reference is null, I'm assuming you're trying to update the adapter inside TopFragment. In this case, get a reference to the TopFragment instance and call an update method on it to update its adapter(in onBottomListClick()):  TopFragment topFragment = (TopFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.topFragment); topFragment.update(clickedEmployee); . Create the update() method inside TopFragment  and in that method update your adapter reference with the new Cursor.

Comment: @Luksprog in the update method would I merge the two cursors together and then swap cursor?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do when you click a row in the bottom list. From your code it looks that you just want to replace the previous employee data with the one selected in the bottom list, in which case you just pass the cursor to the update() method and in that method then call swap() cursor on the adapter in TopFragment. If you want to  append the data of the new selection then you should do the proper  database query to incorporate the old and new data and have a single cursor to pass to update)_.

Comment: @Luksprog I want to take a row from bottomList and add that to the top list when its clicked. If I can do this with a query how would I go about that, any links for suggestions? I have only done WHERE clauses with the DB.

Comment: You cannot reference the Adapter **within** the Fragment from the Activity like this. Please show the `BottomFragment` class too

Comment: @cricket_007 I have updated the code to include TopFragment and BottomFragment, also updated the onBottomListClick to make a query to send the cursor to topFragment's updateMethod.

Comment: I don't see an update method in the topFragment

Comment: Sorry added the method, I was going to try and merge the cursors together and use that after the merge for the adapter, but sounds like that might not be the best way to handle this.

Comment: Why the down votes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to get this to finally work. What I did, is take the cursor from the bottomList, merge it with the TopLists existing cursor, and then pass that cursor to the TopAdapter.

```
public void update(Cursor cursor) {
        MergeCursor mergeCursor = new MergeCursor(new Cursor[]{cursor, mTopCursor});
        TopListCursorAdapter topAdapter = new TopListCursorAdapter(getContext(), mergeCursor);
        mTopListView.setAdapter(topAdapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless Employee's can share ID's, this code will only get you **one** Employee displayed in the ListView. (In Activity)

> ```
> dbHandler.addEmployee(e);
> TopFragment topFragment = (TopFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.topFragment);
> SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
> final Cursor clickedEmployee = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + "employees" + " WHERE " +
>         "Employee_number" + "=" + e.getEmployee_number(), null);
> // change the adapter's Cursor
> topFragment.update(clickedEmployee);
> ```

And so will this code (In TopFragment)

> ```
> int mStartingEmployeeID = 3500075;
> dbHandler = new EmployeeDBHandler(getContext());
> SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
> mTopCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE " + "Employee_number" + "=" + mStartingEmployeeID, null);
> ListView mTopListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.mTopList);
> TopListCursorAdapter topAdapter = new TopListCursorAdapter(getContext(), mTopCursor);
> mTopListView.setAdapter(topAdapter);
> ```

---

You are trying to *add* a row to the adapter, not replace it entirely. So, to do that, I think you want an `INSERT` statement into your database before you mess with any swapping of cursors, then re-write your query such that *all* results that you are trying to insert will come back.

For example, maybe you want `WHERE Employee_number >= " + mStartingEmployeeID` if the ID's are auto-incrementing.

---

Additionally, this may not solve some problems, you are breaching the purpose of the the `dbHandler` instance which is to "encapsulate" your queries.

So, instead of this

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
mTopCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE " + "Employee_number" + "=" + mStartingEmployeeID, null);
```

Recommended way would simply be

```
topCursor = dbHandler.getEmployeeWithId(mStartingEmployeeID);
```

If you already have a similar method that returns `Employee`, then you can instead make a `Employee(Cursor c)` constructor that you'd use like this

```
Employee e = new Employee(dbHandler.getEmployeeWithId(mStartingEmployeeID));
```

---

Comment: I see removing the query from the different spots and placing them into the dbhandler. But how does this help with adding that bottomList clicked employee to the toplist? The top list will always have that person at the start  of the app, they will always be in the toplist. I can remove the query and use the getEmployee method in my dbhandler, but that doesn't help me add the clicked event from bottomList.

Comment: You are too focused on the lower half of my answer. The top was the more important piece. You need to update / change your query so that any inserted employee record is added **to the database**, not the ListView, then use whatever query will be able to display that object.

Comment: If I add that clicked row to the database, wouldn't that add the record twice as they are already in the db?

Comment: That would depend on your UNIQUE database constraints when doing an INSERT. Otherwise, if you are needed to change an existing value that would be an UPDATE. I sounds to me like you are having some misunderstandings of SQL than necessarily how Android components can talk to each other.

Comment: Yes, this is the first time I have used SQLite for anything.

Comment: That's fine. There are other tools that simplify SQLite on Android, or there's tools like Firebase or Parse-Server that are completely different. Each has it's benefits, but it takes some learning before you can integrate them correctly into an app in a good way.